# Carousel last thumb doesn't work

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, carousel

I have a carousel but somehow the last thumb doesn't work, you can double click it and shows wrong large image.. I really can't find the issue :(

---

Here it works with the last thumb: [CAROUSEL](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/28/)

Here it doesn't: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/2juvL/)

---

The script:

```
 $(function() {

        $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                responsive: false,
                circular: false,
                auto: false,
                items: {
                visible: 2,
                width: 1000,
                height: '475'
                },
                scroll: {
                fx: 'crossfade'
            }
        });

        $('#thumbs').carouFredSel({
                responsive: true,
                circular: false,
                infinite: false,
                auto: false,
                prev: '#prev',
                next: '#next',
                items: {
                visible: {
                min: 2,
                max: 4
            },
                width: 254,
                height: 112
            }
        });

        $('#thumbs a').click(function() {
        $('#carousel').trigger('slideTo', '#' + this.href.split('#').pop() );
        $('#thumbs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#carousel').carouFredSel({ needed to be

visible: 1 and NOT visible: 2